# Recommended Open Source Project, UI Development

Tags: open-source, user-interface

I would like to continue to hone my technical (programming/design/etc) skills while contributing back to the community.  I have done quite a bit of work in UI development and feel most comfortable there (I have written a library that is used internally at my company that provides a solid UI with advanced features available out of the box).  Because I feel comfortable here, I would like to use my skills in this area to begin work on an open source project.

What recommendations would the SO community have for a good place to start?  As this would be my first OSS project, something that is relatively easy to get into would be great (although I'm not adverse to a challenge).  Of course, the project should be able to benefit from a UI developer.

Languages I have/can work in: Java, C#, VB (ugh...please no), C++ (my skills are weakest here)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows GUI front-end to *the* Free Software compression library [zlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) is a project named [Wiz](http://www.info-zip.org/WiZ.html). It has not been updated in several years (the latest OS it claims to support is Windows NT), and desperately needs a facelift, if not an entire rewrite. As a result, it really isn't competitive with commercial alternatives like WinZip.

If you can get yourself access to zlib through C# I'd think that would be just about a perfect project for someone like you.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I also like the idea of starting on a smaller project (I checked out the website and looks like it's maintained by one or two individuals).  I'll look into that more.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would like to see [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) UI improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a project that needs your help, it's [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) for Mac. So much potential, so many bugs :(